# Why am I not getting an error when I use PHPUnit + Selenium Server?

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

Why am I not getting an error when I use PHPUnit + Selenium Server to log in with an email and password that doesn't exists?
This is the PHPUnit script.

```
public function testUserNotExists() {
    $this->open('https://dev.example.com/login');
    $this->type("id=email", "1d0ntex1s7@live.com");
    $this->type("id=password", "1d0n73x1s7");
    $this->click("name=login_user");

}
```

When I run it, it doesn't show an error

Terminal: phpunit ExampleTest.php 
PHPUnit 3.6.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.

E...

Time: 29 seconds, Memory: 4.75Mb

There was 1 error:

1) ExampleTest::testTitle

Method assertTitleEquals not defined.

FAILURES!
Tests: 4, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write [assertions](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html#selenium.seleniumtestcase.tables.assertions) to get some failure. Selenium doesn't know what should (or shouldn't) happen after sending some form.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to figure out why it doesn't show errors for hours.